# comparing two columns of a row in python dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I know that one can compare a whole column of a dataframe and making a list out of all rows that contain a certain value with:

```py
values = parsedData[parsedData['column'] == valueToCompare]
```

But is there a possibility to make a list out of all rows, by comparing two columns with values like:

```py
values = parsedData[parsedData['column01'] == valueToCompare01 and parsedData['column02'] == valueToCompare02]
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is completely possible, but I have never tried using `and` in order to mask the dataframe, rather using `&` would be of interest in this case. Note that, if you want your code to be more clear, use `( )` in each statement:

```py
values = parsedData[(parsedData['column01'] == valueToCompare01) & (parsedData['column02'] == valueToCompare02)]
```